# Why does TThread not work in a DLL? But works in a VCL Form application

Tags: delphi, pascal, indy

Why does this thread procedure not work in a DLL library using `TIdTCPServer`, but it works in a VCL Form application?

```
procedure TFormFpsSrv.Display(p_sender : String; p_message : string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil, procedure
                        begin
                          memo1.Lines.Add(getNow + ' | '
                           + p_sender + ' | ' + p_message);
                          end);
end;
```

```
procedure TFormFpsSrv.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
    port        : Integer;
begin
     Display('Serveris',' | Prisijungta portas: '+IntToStr(port));
end;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677594/800214

Answer (score 2):

In a plain DLL, the DLL and EXE have their own copies of the RTL, which are not shared with each other.  As such, calling `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()` in the DLL's code will not work by default, as there is nothing running in the background to process the DLL's requests.

The DLL will have to export a function that calls the [`CheckSynchronize()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.CheckSynchronize) function for its copy of the RTL, and then the EXE will need to call that exported function periodically, such as in a timer, or in the `TApplication(Events).OnIdle` event.

This is not a problem if you create a Runtime Package (BPL) instead of a DLL, and then configure your BPL and EXE to boh use the `rtl` runtime package so that they share the same RTL instance.

Comment: a little mistake I had to be at TThread.Synchronize while TThread.Queue does this change anything? There is perhaps no example of how to do this. There will be a form in the dll library where you will see the log in memo and you will not need to return anything to the main form.

Comment: No, it does not make a difference, because `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()` use the same internal queue in the RTL, and so they both have the same `CheckSynchronize()` requirement.

Comment: Maybe I could get an example with code on how to roughly solve the problem

Comment: Is there something about my proposed solution that is unclear to you? Have the DLL export a function that calls `CheckSynchronize()`. Have the EXE call that exported function periodically. Done. Do I really need to post a code example for such a simple task?

Comment: I write  in my Display procedure:
if IsLibrary then
    MainThreadID := GetCurrentThreadID;

and everything works now

Comment: Just set IsMultiThread to true in your DLL...